# How to test KVM guest CPU maximum allocation limit?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, central-processing-unit

Running Ubuntu 13.04 Host and vm Guest.
Using virtio for hdd, nic. Max-allocaion CPU cores is 6, minimum is 2.
here is a screenshot for clarification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMVFN.png

Ive made a vm with virt-manager just to play with, and to test out kvm.
Alright, I have a decent understand how the memory balloon driver works, but I still dont know how to test if the guest OS can utilize the max setting for cpu cores. From what i gather, the host will start one thread of qemu for each core allocated per vm.

When i run htop inside the guest, it only shows two cores. (also here is the output of cat /proc/cpuinfo: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93a361545130923537da )

How can I "force" the guest to allocate the other 4 cores so that it can show 6 cores in htop?
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no max-min allocation, you allocate a specific number and that's it. The "min-max" you see is what is allocatable, if you don't pick a number, you will get the minimum, which is "2" in this case.
If you want to allocate 6 cores to the VM, you need to explicitly do that

Comment: so, please note the following screenshot: `http://i.imgur.com/GmYQBMP.png`

what do the numbers 2,6 and 32 represent?

Comment: iirc this is just a preparation for a later-on addition of dynamic CPU plugging, not really in use, unless something changed recently. Your best bet is to actually visit the libvirt IRC channel on #OFTC and ask there

Comment: i will do that, thanks. and i had no idea that the "key term" here was cpu hotplugging. this has lead to a more concise answer for me, and this: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/CPUHotPlug

Answer (score 0):

just run some threaded process with some load; the fastest way is to use a shell-based fork-bomb, but this will kill your machine.